# Rundeck webhook for a specific branch

Tags: rundeck

How to configure Rundeck webhook for a specific branch? whenever end user commits the code to that particular branch then the Rundeck job should trigger.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your GIT provider, e.g: on GitHub you can use GitHub Actions to call aby webhook (Rundeck [webhooks](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/webhooks.html#webhooks) included), take a look at [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-github-actions-to-call-webhooks/).

On Gitlab you can configure webhooks when an event occurs. Take a look at [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhook_events.html).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I have another issue when i am installing Rundeck in RHEL machine. After trying to login its showing as "Authentication is required" Any suggestions.